# How to get fragments from backstack when using Android Navigation Component?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, navigation, fragment-backstack

How can I access any of the fragments in backstack when using Android Navigation Component?
Let's sat you navigate to Fragment A then to Fragment B and then to Fragment C using Navigation Component.
Now you want to access Fragment A or Fragment B instance (without popping any fragments) and set a value to one of its fields.
Back in the day, we could do that using findFragmentByTag.
But how can you do it now when using Navigation Component?

Comment: That isn't how you should be [communicating with fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate) at all. All of the techniques in the documentation work with the Navigation Component.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thank you for your comment and including the link. I believe that I had read this before, but they change the documents every damn day! There was some new things that I learned. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the other fragments data in the same activity, using `SharedViewModel` might be a good idea. You can check the `SharedViewModel` example.

```kotlin
class SharedViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val selected = MutableLiveData<Item>()

    fun select(item: Item) {
        selected.value = item
    }
}

class ListFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var itemSelector: Selector

    // Use the 'by activityViewModels()' Kotlin property delegate
    // from the fragment-ktx artifact
    private val model: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        itemSelector.setOnClickListener { item ->
            // Update the UI
        }
    }
}

class DetailFragment : Fragment() {

    // Use the 'by activityViewModels()' Kotlin property delegate
    // from the fragment-ktx artifact
    private val model: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        model.selected.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<Item> { item ->
            // Update the UI
        })
    }
}
```

If you want to see more detail, here is the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing) for the `SharedViewModel`.